# hStmt/cursor error caused by faulty data? 

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, query

Could a  busy hStmt and invalid cursor errors be caused by faulty data?

ODBC and the software that connects to the database is correct and working - i have ran a test with a clean database (that has no user data in it yet and it worked).
I have also used scripts to move data from the old database to the working one.  Errors then appear in the new database.

I'm unable to locate any problem with the database itself - the tables are all there, procedures work, primary keys, options match.

I've even rebuilt several non critical tables.

However, since it is an interconnected database, simple copy-and-paste to the new database can easily result in some unwanted ID/serial mismatch and render the new database useless.

I've noticed this behavior: ID numbers seems to skip.  For instance, it jumped from 11 to 247 - and that table requires specific user input and over 200 "unfinished" queries to it etc - this doesn't seem to be reasonable.

The hStmt error seems to generally happen when a specific value is being selected by the server software, rendering the following steps useless.

Could it be caused by corrupted data?  When it selects, its just 1 short integer.

Comment: Still the same problem as this? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23009/invalid-cursor-state-not-a-programming-issue-softare-ok-tested-connection-t If so, why not just edit that question?

Comment: for this one it was the tblguild issue, now its related to a tbl general with focused on the hsmt error. The previous one, for  a unknown reason vanished by itself.

Comment: its over odbc.  The software problem was eliminated  by testing it with original database, also by using clean copy of  the software and it runs fine for others who use the same file. 
It is over sql server driver (the native isn't fully supported by the developer). Its something that has worked fine for years, yet just suddenly failed.
The database itself has not been changed and  server software ether uses procedures or queries to read/write/select data, but makes no changes to the tables or creates them.